# widget lost data when device orientation change

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

i have developed a application, which have widget, these are working well, but i change the orientation of device, it display well. but  some time  when i change the orientation data does not display. any one may help me, why this issue occur some thing time.
 here is code

```
 @Override
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
            super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
            Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider ENTER onUpdate");
            String str = null;
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("userInformation", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (prefs != null)
{
                str = prefs.getString("ImageURL", "").toString();
            }
            if (str != null && str != "") {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider (Account logined)");

                for (int j = 0; j < appWidgetIds.length; j++) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
                    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[j]);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

                    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.facedroid_widget_layout);
                    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[j], R.id.listTasks, intent);

                    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.rl_complete_widget, View.GONE);
                    // The empty view is displayed when the collection has no items.
                    // It
                    // should be a sibling
                    // of the collection view.

                    /******** Click Listener for All external items ***********/
                    // Register an onClickListener
                    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);

                    clickIntent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION_FACEDROID_LOGO_BUTTON);
                    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds[j]);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent_facedroid_logo = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rl_topManagerBar_logo, pendingIntent_facedroid_logo);

                    clickIntent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION_COMMENT_BUTTON);
                    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds[j]);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent_commentBtn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.commentBtn, pendingIntent_commentBtn);

                    clickIntent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
                    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds[j]);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent_cameraBtn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.cameraBtn, pendingIntent_cameraBtn);

                    clickIntent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION_CHECKIN_BUTTON);
                    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds[j]);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent_checkinBtn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.checkinBtn, pendingIntent_checkinBtn);

                    clickIntent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION_REFRESH_BUTTON);
                    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds[j]);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent_refreshBtn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refreshBtn, pendingIntent_refreshBtn);
                    /******** Click Listener for All external items ***********/

                    clickIntent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION_ITEM_CLICK);
                    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[j]);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
                    PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listTasks, toastPendingIntent);

                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[j], remoteViews);
                }

            } else {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider (Account not logined)");

                for (int j = 0; j < appWidgetIds.length; j++) {

                    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.facedroid_widget_layout);
                    /******** Click Listener for All external items ***********/
                    // Register an onClickListener
                    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);

                    clickIntent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION_COMPLETE_WIDGET_CLICK);
                    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds[j]);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent_widget_top_bar = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rl_complete_widget, pendingIntent_widget_top_bar);

                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[j], remoteViews);
                }
            }

            Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider EXIT onUpdate");
    //      super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }
```

// here  is code of Onreceive  Method

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent main_intent) {

        super.onReceive(context, main_intent);
        Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider ENTER onReceive");

        // all the intents get handled by this method
        // mainly used to handle self created intents, which are not
        // handled by any other method

        // the super call delegates the action to the other methods

        // for example the APPWIDGET_UPDATE intent arrives here first
        // and the super call executes the onUpdate in this case
        // so it is even possible to handle the functionality of the
        // other methods here
        // or if you don't call super you can overwrite the standard
        // flow of intent handling
        String str = null;
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("userInformation", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (prefs != null) {
            str = prefs.getString("ImageURL", "").toString();
        }
        if (str != null && str != "") {
            Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider (Account logined)");

            if (main_intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider UpdateAction");
                String updateType = main_intent.getStringExtra("updateType");
                Logger.d(TAG, "updateType=" + updateType);
                if (updateType != null) {
                    if (updateType.equals("single")) {
                        final int appWidgetId = main_intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 0);
                        final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                        updateAppWidgetSingle(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
                    } else if (updateType.equals("multiple")) {
                        final int[] appWidgetIds = (int[]) main_intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
                        final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                        updateAppWidgetMultiple(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
                    }
                }
            } else if (main_intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION_ITEM_CLICK)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider ItemClick");
                // int appWidgetId =
                // main_intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                // AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
                int viewIndex = main_intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, 0);

                LinkInfo info_s = null;
                try {
                    info_s = public_feed.DATA.get(viewIndex);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive() " + e.getMessage().toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive() e=null onReceive");
                    }
                }

                if (info_s != null) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SinglePostActivityWidget.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.putExtra("LinkInfo", info_s);
                    context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
                }

            } else if (main_intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION_FACEDROID_LOGO_BUTTON)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider FacedroidLogoButtonClicked");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                ComponentName component_name = new ComponentName("com.platinumapps.facedroid", "com.platinumapps.activities.Splash_Activity");
                intent.setComponent(component_name);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                if (intent != null) {
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

            } else if (main_intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION_COMMENT_BUTTON)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider CommentButtonClicked");

                Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), StatusShareICS.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

            } else if (main_intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider CameraButtonClicked");

                Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), PhotoSharePopup_widget.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

            } else if (main_intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION_CHECKIN_BUTTON)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider CheckinButtonClicked");

                Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), widget_place_checkin_dialog.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

            } else if (main_intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION_REFRESH_BUTTON)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider RefreshButtonClicked");

                refresh_indicator = true;
                final int appWidgetId = main_intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
                final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

                RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.facedroid_widget_layout);
                updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.pb_refreshing, View.VISIBLE);
                updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.refreshBtn, View.INVISIBLE);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);

                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.facedroid_widget_layout);
                        updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.pb_refreshing, View.GONE);
                        updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.refreshBtn, View.VISIBLE);
                        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
                    }
                }, 1000 * 10);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
                intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
                intent.putExtra("updateType", "single");
                intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);

            } else if (main_intent.getAction().equals(REFRESH_END)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider RefreshEnd");

                if (refresh_indicator) {

                    int appWidgetId = main_intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
                    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

                    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.facedroid_widget_layout);
                    updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.pb_refreshing, View.GONE);
                    updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.refreshBtn, View.VISIBLE);
                    mgr.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
                    refresh_indicator = false;
                }

                // if (WidgetService.isOrientationChanged) {
                // Log.e(TAG, "WidgetService.isOrientationChanged=true");
                // WidgetService.isOrientationChanged = false;
                // final int appWidgetId =
                // main_intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                // 0);
                // final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager =
                // AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                // updateAppWidgetSingle(context, appWidgetManager,
                // appWidgetId);
                // } else {
                // Log.e(TAG, "WidgetService.isOrientationChanged=false");
                // }
            }

        } else {
            Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider (Account not logined)");

            Toast.makeText(context, "Please login to facedroid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (main_intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION_COMPLETE_WIDGET_CLICK)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider HeaderWidgetClicked");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                ComponentName component_name = new ComponentName("com.platinumapps.facedroid", "com.platinumapps.activities.Splash_Activity");
                intent.setComponent(component_name);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                if (intent != null) {
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

            } else if (main_intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION_WIDGET_CONTAINER_AREA)) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider ContainerWidgetClicked");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                ComponentName component_name = new ComponentName("com.platinumapps.facedroid", "com.platinumapps.activities.Splash_Activity");
                intent.setComponent(component_name);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                if (intent != null) {
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }

        String updateType = main_intent.getStringExtra("updateType");
        Logger.d(TAG, "updateType=" + updateType);
        if (updateType != null) {
            if (updateType.equals("single")) {
                final int appWidgetId = main_intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 0);
                final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                updateAppWidgetSingle(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
            } else if (updateType.equals("multiple")) {
                final int[] appWidgetIds = (int[]) main_intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
                final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                updateAppWidgetMultiple(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
            }
        }

        Logger.d(TAG, "WidgetProvider EXIT onReceive");
        //super.onReceive(context, main_intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when u rotate your phone the activity destroyed and recreated. so the variable gets reinitialized. that is why `data does not display`. u can overcome this by blocking the destroy of activity onRotation. to achieve this put this in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="FriendPickerActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

i am pointing on `android:configChanges="orientation"`

or u can use `onSaveInstanceState ()` and `onRestoreInstanceState ()` in your activity

Comment: I have the EXACT problem with a widget I've developed.  I will be adding this little trick to the code.  Let us hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

When the orientation of the device is changed the Activity's onCreate Method is called. So you will have to persist data and then retreive it in onCreate method. Look at
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Your answer is good, and related to the mine topic, but  i have handled this. this problem is occure only some time, not every time. this problem was related to the Super class call.